# sed alters windows line endings unintentionally. How can I avoid that?

Tags: sed, newlines, whitespace

I am developing in linux a portable application, in which I wanted to remove trailing spaces from some source files, which have windows style line endings. The line endings should not be changed to unix.

The code -using 'sed'- was simple enough to find online:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//' myfile
```

the problem is that after the operation, `diff` states that ALL lines in the file (and the .bak that was generated) differ. This cannot be true of course. The specific file had only 1 line with a trailing space.

Checking with a hexdump (I used `od -x myfile`) utility it is apparent that the 1st line of the original file ends in "0d0a" , whereas in the sed-edited file it ends in "0a".

I have not been able to find any information about how to perform the trailing spaces removal without affecting the line endings. Is there a way ?

if the "Carriage return" character is part of the "[[:space:]]" regex group, then perhaps this

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[ \t]+$//' myfile
```

should work. But it does not - it creates an identical file.
I have also tried the "-e" flag and even no flag at all. Still the generated file is identical to the original and no trailing space is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the  (\r = ^M = 0x0D) character belongs to the `space` "character class". Allow for it in your second regex, either with a wildcard:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[ \t]+.$/\r/' myfile
```

or the specific char, like

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[ \t]+\r$/\r/' myfile
```

Should your `sed` not recognize the `\r` notation, try other. like hex `\x0D` or octal `\015`.